# Weird scaffolding create error in Grails

Tags: grails, scaffolding

I just started using Grails 2.4.0 and I'm running into a weird error when creating objects through scaffolding. The first create works fine, but any time I try to go to the create action following the first create, I get this exception:

```
Message: fromIndex = -1
    Line | Method
->>  620 | <init>                in java.util.SubList
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    775 | <init>                in java.util.RandomAccessSubList
|    484 | subList . . . . . . . in java.util.AbstractList
|    251 | doAppend              in org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton
|     66 | appendLoopOnAppenders in org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl
|    206 | callAppenders         in org.apache.log4j.Category
|    391 | forcedLog . . . . . . in     ''
|    856 | log                   in     ''
|    192 | logMessage . . . . .  in org.slf4j.impl.GrailsLog4jLoggerAdapter
|    167 | error                 in     ''
|    213 | error . . . . . . . . in org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLog
|    189 | doFilter              in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter . . . . . .  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|     53 | doFilter              in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter
|     49 | doFilter . . . . . .  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter
|     82 | doFilter              in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
|   1145 | runWorker . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run                   in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run . . . . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
| Error 2014-05-26 13:24:28,800 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] ERROR [/PantryWizardAdmin].[default]  - Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/PantryWizardAdmin] threw exception [org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: fromIndex = -1] with root cause
Message: fromIndex = -1
    Line | Method
->>  620 | <init>                in java.util.SubList
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    775 | <init>                in java.util.RandomAccessSubList
|    484 | subList . . . . . . . in java.util.AbstractList
|    251 | doAppend              in org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton
|     66 | appendLoopOnAppenders in org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl
|    206 | callAppenders         in org.apache.log4j.Category
|    391 | forcedLog . . . . . . in     ''
|    856 | log                   in     ''
|    192 | logMessage . . . . .  in org.slf4j.impl.GrailsLog4jLoggerAdapter
|    167 | error                 in     ''
|    213 | error . . . . . . . . in org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLog
|    189 | doFilter              in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter . . . . . .  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|     53 | doFilter              in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter
|     49 | doFilter . . . . . .  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter
|     82 | doFilter              in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
|   1145 | runWorker . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run                   in java.util.concurrent.
ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run . . . . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

It happens with any object I try to create. The first works, the second and any subsequent always fail and I end up having to restart the server.

Comment: This may be related to a bug in Grails 2.4.0 which has been fixed for Grails 2.4.1. See https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11430.

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely the same issue.

Comment: Could you test if the workaround (patching 2.4.0) works for you? see the recent comments in https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11430