# Grails scaffolding causing NullPointerException

Tags: grails, scaffolding

I'm new to Grails (predominantly a Java Developer), dipping my toe into Grails.

My initial experience is generally good, but I'm experiencing some problems with the scaffold feature...

I've installed STS (3.5.1.RELEASE) and have installed the Grails(2.4.0) and Groovy plugins.
I created a Domain Class (Rat) and a Controller class and added a scaffold to the Controller.

```
package testnull

class RatController {
    static scaffold = Rat

    def index() { }
}
```

I started up the app and the scaffold displays fine, but after a few cycles of creating editing and deleting it throws a NullPointerException:

```
    Line | Method
->>  527 | doFilter  in /rat/create
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

Caused by GrailsTagException: Error executing tag <g:form>: Error executing tag <g:render>: null
->>   35 | doCall    in /rat/create
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

Caused by GrailsTagException: Error executing tag <g:render>: null
->>   30 | doCall    in /rat/create
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

Caused by NullPointerException: null
->>  333 | hash      in java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    988 | get       in     ''
|    141 | getValue  in grails.util.CacheEntry
|     81 | getValue  in     ''
|     30 | doCall .  in rat_create$_run_closure2_closure24
|     35 | doCall    in rat_create$_run_closure2
|     37 | run . . . in rat_create
|    189 | doFilter  in PageFragmentCachingFilter.java
|     63 | doFilter  in AbstractFilter.java
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run       in java.lang.Thread
```

If I 'generate-views' and remove the 'scaffold' it all works fine.

Is this a known issue?

Regards,
Chris

Comment: Are `RatController` and `Rat` in the same package? What happens if you remove the index action and try again? What does the `Rat` class look like?

Comment: Whoops, this is a duplicate! :-(
Never spotted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23875109/weird-scaffolding-create-error-in-grails)

The fix is contained in 2.4.1 build

Comment: Ah! Well, there ya go. :)